# Illustrator's Paintbrush and Pencil tools are too smooth

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush, drawing-tablet

I am trying to trace lines over a photograph using the **Paintbrush** tool. However, no matter what settings I put in the **Paintbrush** options, the lines I draw are distorted beyond recognition. I am using a Wacom ET-04-5-U, if that has anything to do with it.

Here is an example with maximum possible fidelity and smallest smoothness:

[image]

*The Settings*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyH0b.jpg

*The Result*

And the results are just as bad with the **Pencil** tool.

**What am I doing wrong, and how can I create more precise strokes when drawing in Illustrator?**

Comment: I could not replicate your issue with similar brush/ pencil settings. Paths were exactly what I drew. Maybe try it with a mouse instead of the wacom and see if the difficulty persists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess would be that **whopper** of a Fidelity setting.

From AI help:

> Fidelity can range from 0.5 to 20 pixels; the **higher the value, the smoother and less complex the path**. Controls the amount of smoothing that Illustrator applies when you use the tool. 
> <sub>(emphasis mine)</sub>

I **absolutely** understand the confusion and *why* a high Fidelity setting may seem advantageous, but it's not. The way the setting works is counter-intuitive . The *higher* the Fidelity setting the **less** Fidelity (adherence) to the original path there is. You should expect **more** smoothing the higher the Fidelity value.

An easy way to remember is **More** Fidelity = **More** Smoothing.

Of course, this depends upon how fast you draw, the scale you draw at, and how detailed you are trying to create paths.

All I see in your videos is the extreme Fidelity being applied when you stop drawing. i.e. path smoothing.

I **always** set `Fidelity` to **1** and `Smoothness` to **1%**. Smoothness at 0 tends to be a bit *too* accurate where the small hiccups and twitches are concerned. 1% helps reduce those a bit. Not implying these settings will work for you, merely what I have preferred for years.

Comment: Ah, I see! So, "1% Fidelity" actually translates into proper English to "A lot of Fidelity" and "100% Fidelity" translates into "No Fidelity as all"! Who am I, to think people at Adobe speak proper English... Hopefully they're not telling promising "100% Fidelity" to their life partners...

Comment: @MicroMachine yeah it's backwards to most. But then I think of "flatness" which controls how smooth an arc is. Flatness works similarly... more flatness means a less flat curve, not more flat... so it may be a math or engineering thing.

Comment: Hahah, it’s definitely not a semantics thing! ;)